# Multipartentity equivalent for iOS

Tags: android, ios, post, multipartentity

It seems that there are no objective-c libraries that you can import that are equivalent to the apache libraries android for android.

So what is the best way to send a video file to server from an iOS app if I'd like to use the same php POST script?

If I use `NSMutableRequest`, how can I emulate the multipartentity? Would the following blocks of code be equivalent?

```
multipartentity.addpart("file", new FileBody(file));
mulitpartentity.addpart("form_submitted", new StringBody("true"));
```

&

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];   
[str appendFormat:@"file=%@", self.fileData];
[str appendFormat:@"&form_submitted=%@", @"true"];

[body appendData:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[theRequest setHTTPBody:body];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a multipart entity type functionality in iOS you have to use a third party libraries --- ASIHttpRequest Libraries !

Download it from [Here](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request)

You have to use ASIFormDataRequest Class for implementing the multipart entity type functionality, which is included in the ASIHttpRequest Library...

Also see the following [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779755/unable-to-upload-video-using-asihttpformdatarequest-iphone)

Also if u need you can refer this [Blog](http://nathanmock.com/archives/posting-form-data-from-ios#comment-3914)

Hope it Helps !!