# Unable to upload video using ASIHttpFormDataRequest --- iPhone

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest, multipartform-data

I want to make a request in maultipartform, in this format --

```
<form action="http://xyz.com/web/video/formupload/01f7e4d2-9484-44ed-9e5d-bb4b7ff67739" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data" ">
    <input id="uploadedFile" type="file" name="uploadedFile"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="TOKEN"/>
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

I am using asiformdatarequest class for this purpose ..
This is my code below

```
ASIFormDataRequest *videoUploadRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[tokenValue objectForKey:@"url"]]];
    [videoUploadRequest setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];
    [videoUploadRequest addData:[tokenValue objectForKey:@"token"] forKey:@"token"];
    [videoUploadRequest addData:video withFileName:@"New Video" andContentType:(@"video/*") forKey:@"uploadedFile"];

[videoUploadRequest startSynchronous];

NSError *error = [videoUploadRequest error];

if (!error)
{
    NSString *response = [videoUploadRequest responseString];
    NSLog(@"upload response: %@", response);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Eror -- %@", error);
}
```

I am getting an error saying

```
Eror -- Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=3 "Authentication needed" UserInfo=0x1e5ee090 {NSLocalizedDescription=Authentication needed}
```

Please could anyone tell if there is something wrong with the code..
Format of the request or anything else..

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The error say's you should have to send your Authenticate parameters(e.g. user id and password) then upload your video.

Comment: I am already authenticated..
and i get a token value & URL when i say i want to upload a video

and using that i am uploading the video !

Comment: check whether upload service have the privilege to upload video in to the server or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer !
Was sending token in improper format.
here it is !

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:[tokenValue objectForKey:@"url"]]; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];

ASIFormDataRequest *videoUploadRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[videoUploadRequest setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];

[videoUploadRequest addPostValue:[tokenValue objectForKey:@"token"] forKey:@"token"];
[videoUploadRequest addData:video withFileName:@"uploadedFile" andContentType:(@"video/*") forKey:@"uploadedFile"];

[videoUploadRequest startSynchronous];

NSError *error = [videoUploadRequest error];


if (!error)
{
    NSString *response = [videoUploadRequest responseString];
    NSLog(@"upload response: %@", response);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error -- %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Please I am new to iPhone Development and i want to upload a video file to server.Please post your whole code. Thanks in advance